# Converted copied text from textbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to convert text which user is copying from my textbox.

For example:

```
text of myTextBox is "12,34"
```

and I want to give user:

```
myTextBox.Text.Replace(",",".") <. "12.34"
```

Then he could paste this text anywhere in this format (for example in webbrowser).

Anyone know simple way to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: What have you got so far? What part don't you understand?

Comment: Do you want to convert your string to double regrdless regional setting on a PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you working on windows based application if yes than you can make use of ClipBoard class

```
            string strData=default(string);

             object obj = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);

            if (obj == null)
            {

                return;
            }
            else
                 strData = obj.ToString();

           strData = strData.Replace(",",".") 


           Clipboard.SetData("Text", strData);
```

Now when user paste somewhere , it will use formatted text.